# Досрочный выход из блокирующего вызова WriteFile

Tags: delphi, com-порт

Работаю с СОМ-портом в режиме RS-485. Порт открыт без перекрытого в/в, то есть все операции записи и чтения должны быть блокирующими. Однако выход из WriteFile завершается досрочно, до фактического завершения передачи. Соответственно, RTS сбрасывается раньше времени, и до получателя доходит только обрывок пакета данных.
Пока проблему удалось решить частично, добавив после WriteFile цикл ожидания, пока не пройдет расчетное время на передачу пакета.

```
SetRTS(True);
// здесь засекаем время и определяем, сколько времени нужно ждать
WriteFile(FComPort.Handle, Buffer, Size, bytes_sent, nil);
// здесь ждем, пока отмеренное время не закончилось
SetRTS(False);
```

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с такой проблемой?

Comment: А на чем это написано не подскажите?

Comment: Object Pascal в данном случае. Здесь не полноценный код показан, а суть проблемы и попытки её решения

Comment: похожая штука у меня была когда либ сокетов делал с  без ssl выход был только когда все пакеты улетели c ssl досрочно. т.к все в сокет ssl запихивалось и там ждало пока отправится если с в отдельном потоке выполнялось то ваше не понятно сколько нужно ждать.  сокетами решается посылом обратного ответа после закачки обычно серваки сами такие заголовки отправляют. не знаю что делает ваша WriteFile (мб эт ваша какая проц) но добавлять константу ожидания для разных пакетов это не лучшая затея. найдите способ получить событие что все отправилось.

Comment: WriteFile - стандартная API-функция Windows. Я пытался ждать события TXEMPTY с помощью WaitCommEvent - результат был тот же, из этой функции возврат был тоже до завершения фактической передачи. Похоже, проблема в каких-то настройках драйвера, но где конкретно - непонятно.